# How to generate a logical string in python from nested json elements

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the below nested json structure where I wanted to derived an logical expression based on the structure.

```
{
   "Name":"Main_Rules",
   "Rules":[
      {
         "logic":"A1",
         "or":[
            {
               "logic":"B",                  
               "or":[
                  {
                     "logic":"C1",                        
                     "or":[
                        {
                           "logic":"D",                               
                           "or":[
                              {
                                 "logic":"E",                                     
                                 "or":[]
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "logic":"F",
               "or":[
                  
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "logic":"G1",
         "or":[]
      }
   ]
}
```

The expected string out of the above json is `(( A1 OR ( ( B OR (C1 OR D OR E)) AND F )) AND G1 )`

```
(
 ( A1 
    OR 
      ( 
        ( 
          B OR  (C1 OR D OR E)
        )
        AND F
      )
 )
 AND G1
)
```

Following is how the result string is derived.

`A1` is `OR` condition to result of `( B OR (C1 OR D OR E)) AND F )`

`B` is `OR` condition to result of `(C1 OR D OR E)` and the result of `(B OR (C1 OR D OR E))` is in `AND` condition to `F`

The result of `( A OR ( ( B OR (C OR D OR E)) AND F ))` is in `AND` condition to final `G1`

If there is no OR condition within A1 then the expected logical string should be `(A1 AND G1)`

So far I tried string split and iterating the characters, however I couldn't achieve the expected result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://github.com/nadirizr/json-logic-py

You can edit the code to suit your file structure or use their structure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).